# Array of booleans into one numeric and back

Tags: java, boolean, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I need to turn an array of booleans (30 and more) into one numeric to keep it in one cell of table in db, I want to use java but not native functions of DBs.
So help me to turn, for ex, 10 into [1,3] and back.
(10 = 0^0 + 2^**1** + 0^2 + 2^**3**)

Comment: thank for a response but that is not what I want: I need to keep a **lot** of boolean values (let them be 1 and 0) into **one** decimal value

Comment: Ah OK.... So go the opposite way?  So do you have an array of `boolean`, or do you have an array of integers that give you the position of which bits are ON/OFF?  Your requirements and your example contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode up to `32` booleans in an `int` as follows (the method **won't error** on more than `32` `boolean`s, but won't be able to unpack correctly) :

```
public static int pack (boolean[] values) {
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        n <<= 0x01;
        if(values[i]) {
            n |= 0x01;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Equivalent you can pack `64` bools in a `long`.

And unpack it with:

```
public static boolean[] unpack (int n) {
    boolean[] res = new boolean[32];
    for(int i = 31; n != 0x00; i--) {
        if((n&0x01) != 0x00) {
            res[i] = true;
        }
        n >>>= 0x01;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note however that **you don't encode the length of the array** - there is no reliable way to reconstruct the length of the array, you either need to know it in advance, or store it in the database. If later you unpack the int in a boolean, the array will be `32` booleans long. If you encoded `30` bools however, you can **ignore the first 2**.

Or if you **know the length of the array**:

```
public static boolean[] unpack (int n, int length) {
    boolean[] res = new boolean[length];
    for(int i = length-1; n != 0x00 && i >= 0; i--) {
        if((n&0x01) != 0x00) {
            res[i] = true;
        }
        n >>>= 0x01;
    }
    return res;
}
```

See this [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/l9) for a demo.